# ActiveCell.Formula Run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the sum of columns G:26 to 1 above the "Total Service Fees" cell. I am running into a Run-time error '1004'. Application-defined or object-defined error. Does anyone know what this could be from?

```
Worksheets(1).Select
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "Total Service Fees"
Set rng1 = Range("F15:F100").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(G26:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select & ")"
Else
    MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
End If
```

I get the right answer, but I still get this error.

Comment: You don't want to use the `Select` method in that formula, I bet. To elaborate: open the immediate window (CTRL+G) and type this -- including the `?` , then press enter: `?"=SUM(G26:" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select & ")"` You should see that this is not a valid formula.

Comment: What would you suggest instead? It is giving me =SUM(G26:True)

Comment: That `=SUM(G26:True)` is what you are telling the code to assign as the formula. This is not valid, so you'll need to supply a valid `A1`-style range identifier.

Comment: + 1 Classic case of why you shouldn't use `ActiveCell`, `Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the use of `SELECT`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

When you have identified the cell which had the search text then simply retrieve the row of that cell and use that. See this example (UNTESTED).

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strSearch As String
Dim r As Long

With Worksheets(1)
    strSearch = "Total Service Fees"
    Set rng1 = .Range("F15:F100").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        r = rng1.Row
        .Range("G" & r).Formula = "=SUM(G26:G" & r & ")"
    Else
        MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
    End If
End With
```

**Note**: I have not done any error handling. You will have to take care of that. For example, what if the search text if found on `F26`?

Comment: This gives me the inclusive row of TotalServiceFees when doing the SUM

Comment: Is this what you want then? `r = rng1.Row -1`

Comment: And if you want the formula in G cell next to F cell where yyou have found the text then don't change the above. but change `.Range("G" & r).Formula = "=SUM(G26:G" & r & ")"` to `.Range("G" & r).Formula = "=SUM(G26:G" & (r-1) & ")"`

Comment: Yeah, I had to make that little change but it works now. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Set rng1 = Range("F15:F100").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
```

I think your problem lies here. Try declaring the worksheet or setting a variable to the appropriate sheet.

```
Dim WS as Worksheet
Set WS = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Enter Sheet Name")
Set rng1 = WS.Range("F15:F100").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
```